# Laravel Sanctum and MongoDb Call to a member function prepare() on null in file Error

Tags: php, laravel-9

Am trying to use laravel sanctum to create tokens. I followed all the configuration steps but when am trying  to issue tokens am getting the following error

```
Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in file C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 539

#0 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(753): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;Illuminate\Database\{closure}()
#1 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(720): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;runQueryCallback()
#2 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(546): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;run()
#3 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(498): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;statement()
#4 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection-&gt;insert()
#5 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(3322): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor-&gt;processInsertGetId()
#6 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1869): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder-&gt;insertGetId()
#7 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1330): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder-&gt;__call()
#8 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1295): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;insertAndSetId()
#9 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1138): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;performInsert()
#10 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php(322): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;save()
#11 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(306): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany-&gt;Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\{closure}()
#12 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php(323): tap()
#13 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\HasApiTokens.php(59): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany-&gt;create()
#14 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php(33): App\Models\User-&gt;createToken()
#15 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\UserController-&gt;registerUser()
#16 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction()
#17 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(260): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch()
#18 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController()
#19 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(798): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run()
#20 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#21 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\app\Http\Middleware\EnsureValidUserDetails.php(36): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#22 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): App\Http\Middleware\EnsureValidUserDetails-&gt;handle()
#23 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#24 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle()
#25 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(126): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#26 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequest()
#27 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#28 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle()
#29 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(25): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#30 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful-&gt;Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\{closure}()
#31 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#32 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(26): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#33 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful-&gt;handle()
#34 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#35 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(799): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#36 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack()
#37 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(740): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute()
#38 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute()
#39 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch()
#40 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#41 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#42 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#43 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle()
#44 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#45 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#46 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle()
#47 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#48 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle()
#49 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#50 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle()
#51 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#52 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors-&gt;handle()
#53 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#54 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle()
#55 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#56 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#57 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter()
#58 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle()
#59 C:\Users\Weston\Projects\E-site-api-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php(16): require_once(&#039;...&#039;)
#60 {main}
```

The register function that is giving me this error is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //Registering all new users
    function registerUser(Request $request){
        $user = User::create(
            [
                'firstName'=> $request->firstName,
                'middleName' => $request->middlename,
                'surname' => $request->surname,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phoneNumber' => $request->phoneNumber,
                'dob' => $request->dob,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                ]
            );

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $request->firstName . " " . $request->surname . " added successfully",
            ])->setStatusCode(201);
    }
```

My user model is as follows

```
namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'firstName',
        'middleName',
        'surname',
        'dob',
        'gender',
        'phoneNumber'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I tried to remove the `$token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken` my user was registerd successfully but if i write that statement again am getting the same error. i have been working and watching various tutorials but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you please show your connection configurations?

Comment: The .env configurations 
FRONT_END_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=SHOES  my database.php are                                                                        
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'SHOES'),
        ],
 and default is set to mongodb